# Can Cake Php Validation clear input field value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Can Cake Php Validation clear input field value

```
var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
       'isUnique' => array (

           'rule' => 'isUnique',

           'message' => 'This Person name already exists.'
       )
    )
);
```

If error persist in validation, I want to clear `name` field value. Is it possible to do so with cake php validation itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom validation rule if you wanted.

```
var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
       'isUnique' => array (
           'rule' => 'ifNotUniqueClear', // use custom rule defined below
           'message' => 'This Person name already exists.'
       )
    )
);

function ifNotUniqueClear(&$data) {
    $field = key($data);

    // see if the record exists
    $user = $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            $field => $data[$field]
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));

    if ($user) {
        // unset or empty it, your choice
        unset($this->data[$this->alias][$field]);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried with above code, but the corresponding text field is not cleared. when I `print_r($this->data)`, the corresponding  variable is unsetted, still the input field shows the corresponding value..

Comment: Did you check the `$this->data` within the validation rule? Is it making it to the validation rule? Does it find the user (`debug($user)` in the validation rule).

Comment: Yes, `$this->data` inside the validation rule. `debug($user)` will give array of corresponding `$user` details.

Comment: Is your controller action doing something with the data? Other behaviors? If the data is unset by the time it reaches the view then it shouldn't be populating the field. Also, try `$this->data[$this->alias][$field] = ''` instead, just out of curiosity.