# Is there a way to remove field value using model in CakePHP?

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp, model

I'm developing an application in CakePHP 2.7 and I have a form where that sends off an Ajax request from a file input and returns some information. This information is  then stored inside a hidden form field.

I have a custom validation rule that checks against the hidden field and another to see if both have been submitted as the system can only handle one. When the validation rule returns false it flags up an invalidate message to notify the user of the issue. However now I am left with an issue where the hidden field still contains a value and so does the other field the user filled out but I can't remove the value from the hidden field.

**Is there any way I can remove the value from the hidden field inside the model?**

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412257/can-cake-php-validation-clear-input-field-value) on StackOverflow but it wasn't successsful in helping and dates back to an earlier version of CakePHP based on the date of the question.

Comment: How do you access the data in the hidden field? is it `$this->request->data['Model']['hidden_field_name']` ?

Comment: @dragmosh I access the data in the hidden field using `$this->data[$this->alias]['hidden_field_name'];`

Comment: then `unset($this->data[$this->alias]['hidden_field_name']);` should work if the form is submitted and the page is reloaded. If the page isn't reloaded you should have JavaScript to clear the hidden field when the ajax request returns.